# Error Message: Server was unable to process request. ---> Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, clr, .net-framework-version, iis-8.5

One ASP .NET Application is using

- SQL Server 2012
- IIS 8.5
- .NET Framework 4.0
- Windows server 2012 r2

The application is getting below error in all the load balanced application servers.

```
ERROR  - User System, Module Global, Error caught in Application_Error event event
Error Message: Server was unable to process request. ---> Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.
Stacktrace: 
Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)   
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Why this error is occurring?

After restarting the IIS in all application servers, the issue got resolved. But we need to know how this is getting triggered to ensure it doesn’t happen again.

Comment: The error message you got indicates a kind of rare crash of .NET CLR runtime, so unless you grab a full memory crash dump for further analysis, it is impossible to tell what exactly is the cause.

Comment: This is a very generic error, there is no specific cause for this. you can try to debug the cause using IIS Debug Diagnostics Tool. this tool will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.